# "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence." when using word vectors as features

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have vectorized a whole bunch of words from a wikipedia corpus. One word vector example :

```
 [ 0.56694877  0.79432029 -0.00573941  0.37489545 -0.11976419 ...  0.76672393]
```

What my data looks like:

```
Word Frequency     Word Vector    Known (label)

165515                    vector1            0
626252                    vector2            1
....                              ....                  ...
```

I have a data sample of someone's vocabulary (Turkish). Some words are known and some are unknown. I am trying to determine which random word would be known or unknown based on this data.

The vectors were created from Word2Vec (gensim):

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import csv
import numpy as np
from gensim.models import word2vec
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('text.model.bin', binary=True)

with open('1000.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    listwords = csv.reader(csvfile)
    features = []
    labels = []
    n = 0
    for row in listwords:
            if n>=199:
                break
            try:
                line = [int(row[2]),np.array(model[row[0]])]
                features.append(line)
                labels.append(row[1])
                n+=1
            except KeyError:
                pass
                features.append([])
                labels.append([])
                n+=1
clf = SVC()
clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
vocab_obj = model.vocab['anne']
print (clf.predict([vocab_obj.count,model['anne']]))
```

To do this I am using scikit learn. The problem is that I can't figure out how to use these word vectors as features.

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classifier.py", line 28, in <module>
    clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
  File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 151, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64, order='C', accept_sparse='csr')
  File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 521, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
  File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 382, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: You should have a bunch of rows of above data with each row having a label (target) that the word is known and unknown. (If thats the case, please post some samples here).

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Check out my edit for more info